# Joomla3 Loading two diffrent plugin for two diffrent user group in their profile page

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, user-groups, profile

I have two profile plugin (core profile and newly created profile5), How can I load these two plugin with two diffrent user group. (For Register type user load core profile and for Editor load profile5).

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple:
you just need to be sure that you have different Access Level for those groups, if you don't - go and make sure about it. (Manage Users - Access Levels)

Then go to your plugins settins and choose required Access Level for each plugin.